# Can not find desired object from mongoDB database in NodeJs and ExpressJs application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

In my NodeJs and ExpressJs application I've been using mongoDb with mongoD ODM tool.
When I try to get a single object from the database, If I use hard-coded value like

```
collection.find({'a': 3});
```

then it returns the desired object.
But in case I use

```
var id = 3;
collection.find({'a': id});
```

It returns empty array.

Explain:
I have 4 objects in 'documents' collections, in 'myproject database':

```
[ { _id: 599ead7033736662b159836a, a: 1 },
  { _id: 599ead7033736662b159836b, a: 2 },
  { _id: 599ead7033736662b159836c, a: 3 },
  { _id: 599eb2edaf418c6734cccf54, name: 'document name' } 
]
```

In my code when I try to get the single object with property

```
{
    'a': 1
 }
```

I can get the

```
 { _id: 599ead7033736662b159836a, a: 1 }
```

But in case If I try this way:

```
var value = 1;
{
    'a': value
}
```

It returns an empty object.

Example:
Here I try to get all the objects:

```
var findDocuments = function(db, callback) {
    var collection = db.collection('documents');
    collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        console.log(docs)
        callback(docs);
    });
}
```

Here I got all these records:

```
[ { _id: 599ead7033736662b159836a, a: 1 },
  { _id: 599ead7033736662b159836b, a: 2 },
  { _id: 599ead7033736662b159836c, a: 3 },
  { _id: 599eb2edaf418c6734cccf54, name: 'document name' } ]
```

Now If i try to get the single objects with property { 'a': 3 }

```
var findSingleDocuments = function(db, id, callback) {
    var collection = db.collection('documents');
    var myId = {
        'a': 3
    };
    collection.find(myId}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        console.log("Found the following records");
        console.log(docs);
        callback(docs);
    });
}
```

I can get the single following objects:

```
[ { _id: 599ead7033736662b159836c, a: 3 } ]
```

But in case I use the id property insted of the 3

```
var findSingleDocuments = function(db, id, callback) {
    var collection = db.collection('documents');
    var myId = {
        'a': id
    };
    collection.find(myId}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        console.log("Found the following records");
        console.log(docs);
        callback(docs);
    });
}
```

It returns an empty object. But the value of id is 3(I checked in console).

Problem:

//value of id is 3

```
myId = {
    'a': id
};
```

This returns an empty array.

But

```
myId = {
    'a': 3
};
```

returns the the object

```
{ _id: 599ead7033736662b159836c, a: 3 } ]
```

Question:
How can I get the `{ _id: 599ead7033736662b159836c, a: 3 } ]` object using the

```
myId = {
    'a': id
};
```

where `id = 3;`

Comment: Can you check if "id" is an Integer and not a String ?

Comment: I use it like   var id = 3; So it may be integer.

Comment: It's string. I just checked 'typeof(id)' in console

Comment: Thanks Bameza. You got the point. I have to use parseInt(id).

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the object from the database, While using the query, value have to cast to integer type.
So the myId will be

```
var id = 3;
var myId = {
    'a': parseInt(id)
};

collection.find(myId);
```

If this is a object Id, then

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
    var o_id = new ObjectID(id);
```

and use o_id instead of id.